# installation of python module from local folder

Tags: linux, python, module

module requests in missing on my redhat 7.5 machine

this is what we get when we run python with module requests

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/uri", line 6, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

the target is to install the module from local folder as

```
 pip install /opt/my_requests
```

from where we need to download module  requests that fit rhel 7.5?

```
/opt/my_requests -  is a folder
```

Comment: You question is quite unclear ... The "from where" question is the problem of pip, not your ... `pip install <module> <location>` should work ... did you tried it ?

Comment: the target is to install the module from local folder since we not have network on this machine

Comment: Ok, @yael, so please, update your question with this constraint.

Comment: Maybe you can have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159482/pip-install-a-local-git-repository

Comment: Would running `python setup.py install` in the requests dir be an option?